# Stop auto-dowload of pdf files from iframe component in webview component react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, iframe, react-native-webview

I'm trying to render a website which has `iframe` components that are used to render pdf files on the browser in my `react-native` application. But instead of displaying the files like in the browser, the files get automatically downloaded. I have tried to stop the files from downloading but couldn't get it to work.

My code is given below:

```
import React from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default function MCA() {
  return (
    <WebView
      source={{
        uri: "https://kleit.ac.in/master-of-computer-applications/",
      }}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      injectedJavaScript={`document.getElementsByClassName('toolbar-container')[0].style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementsByClassName('thim-nav-wrapper container')[0].style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementsByClassName(' site-footer')[0].style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentDocument.controlsList="nodownload";`}
    />
  );
}
```

The iframe part of the webpage is given below:

```
<iframe src="https://kleit.ac.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/MCA_Student_Placement_Details_2022.pdf" height="500"></iframe>
```

As you can see, in the last line of `injectedJavaScript` attribute I have tried to use `controlsList="nodownload";` but that didn't work. I tried messing with contentDocument property of iframe component but that also didn't seem to work.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I tried asking ChatGPT for help and it gave me the idea to use custom HTML Rendering to disable downloads and replacing `iframe` components with `react-native-pdf` component to display the pdf file. Still figuring out how it would work

Answer (score 0):

A PDF has to download to any device since it cannot be viewed online.

The user has a choice
Only Download first
or
Download & RE-view as inline embeded object frame (if PDF is allowed as potentially safe)

The default if allowed is embed an iframed PDF media object, seen using your working code on the left, what then happens is the browser converts that to an imbedded view as seen on the right.

[image]

In general a server has little to say in the process. other than if the hint is "Download" without a frame, it should "Always download".

The wording of the Chromium/Acrobat viewer is not correct since it **implies** view "without download" which is not true.

What it is trying to say is, *if you have a local file and attempt to open with the browser set to insecure*, I will view it "without download".

[image]

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot @KJ. Your answer gave me a lot of understanding of how the web browsers and iframe component work internally. However I am developing a react native application that is using a component called `react-native-webview` to display the webpage in the app. But iframe isn't compatible with react native (or mobile interface if I've understood it right) so all the files get downloaded

Comment: I would love to know if you have any suggestions on this issue or any idea to solve this issue. Anyways, thanks again for your time : )

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely have a look at these